# Why does reading in an image in PIL(low) break Flask image end point?

Tags: python, image, flask, python-imaging-library

I'm using the Python [Flask framework](http://flask.pocoo.org/) to build a website. Since I'm storing uploaded images in MongoDB, I built a simple endpoint to serve the images by id:

```
@app.route('/doc/<docId>')
def getDoc(docId):
    userDoc = UserDocument.objects(id=docId).first()
    if not userDoc:
        return abort(404)

    return Response(userDoc.file_.read(), mimetype=userDoc.file_.content_type)
```

This works perfectly well. But because the images are often very large I now want to be able to also serve up thumbnails of the original images. So using [Pillow](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/) I want to resize the images, store/cache them in `/tmp` and serve them up when needed. So I started off with this:

```
@app.route('/doc/<docId>')
def getDoc(docId):
    userDoc = UserDocument.objects(id=docId).first()
    if not userDoc:
        return abort(404)

    desiredWidthStr = request.args.get('width')
    desiredHeightStr = request.args.get('height')
    if desiredWidthStr or desiredHeightStr:    
        print 'THUMBNAIL'
        # Load the image in Pillow
        im = Image.open(userDoc.file_)  # <=== THE PROBLEM!!!
        # TODO: resize and save the image in /tmp

    print 'NORMAL'
    return Response(userDoc.file_.read(), mimetype=userDoc.file_.content_type)
```

When I now comment out the line with the problem and open the front page (which loads a couple of images) all images load fine and I see this (as expected):

```
THUMBNAIL
NORMAL
THUMBNAIL
NORMAL
THUMBNAIL
NORMAL
212.xx.xx.xx - - [2015-03-19 16:57:02] "GET /doc/54e74956724b5907786e9918?width=100 HTTP/1.1" 200 139588 0.744827
212.xx.xx.xx - - [2015-03-19 16:57:03] "GET /doc/54e7495c724b5907786e991b?width=100 HTTP/1.1" 200 189494 1.179268
212.xx.xx.xx - - [2015-03-19 16:57:03] "GET /doc/5500c5d1724b595cf71b4d49?width=100 HTTP/1.1" 200 264593 1.416928
```

but when I run the code as I pasted it above (with the problem line not commented) the images don't load, and I see this in the terminal:

```
THUMBNAIL
THUMBNAIL
THUMBNAIL
NORMAL
NORMAL
NORMAL
212.xx.xx.xx - - [2015-03-19 16:58:11] "GET /doc/54e74956724b5907786e9918?width=100 HTTP/1.1" 200 138965 0.657734
212.xx.xx.xx - - [2015-03-19 16:58:11] "GET /doc/54e7495c724b5907786e991b?width=100 HTTP/1.1" 200 188871 0.753112
212.xx.xx.xx - - [2015-03-19 16:58:11] "GET /doc/5500c5d1724b595cf71b4d49?width=100 HTTP/1.1" 200 257495 1.024860
```

Except for these things I see no error whatsoever in the terminal. When I try to load a direct url in the browser it says `The image cannot be displayed because it contains errors.`. I now wonder about two things:

1. Even though all requests seem to be a success (200) I don't see the images in the browser. Why?
2. Even if it would take a while for the image to be loaded into Pillow (which I think it doesn't), I would still expect the images to load in the end.

Does anybody know why the images are not served when I load them into Pillow? All tips are welcome!

Comment: I think the problem is that Image.open is throwing an exception which is being caught somewhere and not reported to the console. Have you tried using `with open('some/local/file.jpg') as f: Image.open(f)`? See if that prints an error or not.

Comment: @JDavidSmith - Hmm, you've got a point. If I do `im = Image.open('/tmp/some_image_file.jpg')` the images serve up nicely. But I also tried `im = Image.open(userDoc.file_)` in the console and that works fine (including resizing and saving in a different location). Plus: it prints out `NORMAL` in the end so it seems to reach to end fine. But this does suggest that there's a problem with the combination of MongoDB and Pillow. I'm researching more now.

Comment: Try wrapping the statement in `try: ... except Exception as e: print(e) raise e`. That will print any error and reraise it (after fixing formatting because can't do newlines in comments)

Comment: @JDavidSmith - Tried that; no error output at all. I'm more and more thinking that it has something to do with the MongoDB GridFS file storage. Or would you have another idea?

Comment: I think I just noticed the problem: `Image.open` will read the entire contents of the file, then you `return Response(userDoc.file_.read(), ...)`. Since the file is already read, that function returns `b""`, which is an invalid image.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't have any problems with Pillow. Your problem is that you are serving an *empty response*. If you are serving a *thumbnail*, you ask Pillow to *read the file*:

```
if desiredWidthStr or desiredHeightStr:    
    print 'THUMBNAIL'
    im = Image.open(userDoc.file_)  # reads from the file object
```

You then try and serve from that *same file object*:

```
if desiredWidthStr or desiredHeightStr:    
    print 'THUMBNAIL'
    # Load the image in Pillow
    im = Image.open(userDoc.file_)  # <=== THE PROBLEM!!!
    # TODO: resize and save the image in /tmp

return Response(userDoc.file_.read(), mimetype=userDoc.file_.content_type)
```

The `userDoc.file_.read()` here will return, at best, a partial image since `Image.open()` has already moved the file pointer. It depends on the image type how much is actually read and where the image pointer is located at by that time.

Add in a *`file.seek()` call* and you'll see your image re-appear:

```
if desiredWidthStr or desiredHeightStr:    
    print 'THUMBNAIL'
    # Load the image in Pillow
    im = Image.open(userDoc.file_)

print 'NORMAL'
userDoc.file_.seek(0)  # ensure we are reading from the start
return Response(userDoc.file_.read(), mimetype=userDoc.file_.content_type)
```