# Why does image file not load from company sharepoint?

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, urllib

I am trying to load an image file from a sharepoint url using Pillow, and pass it to tkinter, but it throws an error when opening the image file. How to fix that?

**Code:**

```
url="https://grouperenault.sharepoint.com/sites/CWG-DAAI/Shared%20Documents/Chatbot_files/images/PNG/image0001.png"
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009021910 Firefox/3.0.7'
headers={'User-Agent':user_agent,} 
request=urllib.request.Request(url,None,headers) #The assembled request
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
data = response.read() # The data u need
im = Image.open(response)
```

**Error:**

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-e84a130b4649> in <module>
      5 response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
      6 data = response.read() # The data u need
----> 7 im = Image.open(image_file)

C:\Users\Public\anaconda\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in open(fp, mode)
   2816     for message in accept_warnings:
   2817         warnings.warn(message)
-> 2818     raise IOError("cannot identify image file %r" % (filename if filename else fp))
   2819 
   2820 

OSError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x000001AE0AF92A68>
```

Comment: This looks like a private site that requires login credentials to access. The return value is probably not an image at all, try printing it out or saving it to a file to inspect it.

Answer (score 0):

[You're serving an empty response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29193831/11089932) after reading the content of `response` to `data`, cf. debug `print` commands below.

Use the content stored in `data` and use `BytesIO` to properly feed `Image.open`:

```py
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
import urllib.request

url = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/88/From_Darkest_Peru%5E_-_geograph.org.uk_-_1452413.jpg'
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009021910 Firefox/3.0.7'
headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}
request = urllib.request.Request(url, None, headers)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
print(response.length)
# 96344
data = response.read()
print(response.length)
# 0
img = Image.open(BytesIO(data))
print(img)
# <PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=640x480 at 0x29A1B3370A0>
```

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:        3.9.1
PyCharm:       2021.1.1
Pillow:        8.2.0
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: after modiying code still i receive the same error "  raise IOError("cannot identify image file %r" % (filename if filename else fp))

OSError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x0000021469D7AA08>"

Comment: Using the exact code I posted, do you get the presented output? If so, there's in fact a problem with the image itself you want to load.